# Backbone model needs another model to fetch before fetching

Tags: backbone.js

This is a really simple problem , model2 needs a parameter that model1 have to fetch, so model2 need that model1 has ended to fetch.

Of course I can fetch the model2 on success of model1 and there are also other way to get around this, but what I'm wondering is what is the less ugly way to do this ?
what do you think ?

Comment: *"and there are also other way to get around this..."* - what are they..? Unless you somehow remove this dependency, The only way is to fetch model2 after model1 fetch succeeds. That's it. Whether you do it in success,  `done()` , `then()`  etc is a matter of choice.

Comment: How are both models related to each other? Are they only separate because of the REST API design and `model1` is only necessary to interact with the API or is `model1` used (=bound to a view) standalone too? Showing a minimal (pseudo) code example would help.